# CloudFront Keeps GET'ting pages from my website

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I set up AWS CloudFront and as Origin my website/ELB, for example: origin = [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) points to ELB.

In the behavior I set up to cache everything that is an image or a CSS.

So basically it's something like this if you go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com):

User -> CloudFront -> ELB (LoadBalancer) -> Website

I noticed that now every few seconds I see requests where the User Agent is "Amazon CloudFront" and the IPs are in the AWS DC.

Do you know how can I identify the User Agent behind it (eg.: the actual user agent and not the Amazon CloudFront UA?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved my issue, bots (google and others) are checking pages automatically but if you forward the headers through the CDN configuration you might be able to see the User Agents and filter based on that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).